# Better string replacing in C#

Tags: c#, replace

Does anyone have an idea which would be better for potential string replacement?

If I have a collection of varying length of strings of varying lengths in which some strings *might* need special replacement of encoded hex values (e.g. =0A, %20... etc)

The "replacements" (there could be multiple) for each string would be handled by a Regular Expression to detect the appropriate escaped hex values

Which would be more efficient?

1. To simply run the replacement on every string in the collection ensuring by brute force that all needed replacements are done
2. To perform a test if a replacement is needed and *only* run the replacement on the strings that need it.

I'm working in C#.

### Update

A little additional info from the answers and comments.

This is primarily for VCARD processing that is loaded from a QR Code

I currently have a regex that uses capture groups to get the KEY, PARAMETERS and VALUE from each KEY;PARAMETERS:VALUE in the VCARD.

Since i'm supporting v 2.1 and 3.0 the encoding and line folding are VERY different so I need to know the version before I decode.

Now it doesn't make sense to me to run the entire regular expression JUST to get the version and apply the approptiate replace to the whole vcard block of text and THEN rerun the regular expression.

To me it makes more sense to just get my capture groups loaded up then snag the version and do the appropriate decoding replacement on each match

Comment: When you tested it what were your results? My guess by the way is don't test just always replace

Comment: I don't know if the .net regex engine returns the original instance if no matches are found. If it does not, it puts higher pressure on the GC, which is an effect that's not trivial to compare against an increased CPU cost. So a simple micro benchmark might not cut it.

Comment: @ConradFrix I'd tend to agree, the .NET framework is heavily optimised, I'd imagine adding a test in front of the replace would be slower... However, does it return the exact same string instance if no replacement is made? Simple to test I guess. Memory footprint could be an issue.

Comment: It sounds like you want to url encode something. Consider using built in methods for this, instead of rolling your own.

Comment: If you have hours to spare looking for this, surely you can spend half an hour writing some code to test & measure this?

Comment: @CodeInChaos This is for VCARD Processing from a decoded QR barcode more specifically Quote-Printable encoding (I'm supporting 2.1 and 3.0) however there are other things loaded from a QR Barcode that could use the same kind of decoding but might use something like URL encoding though neither encoding method would be guaranteed.

Comment: @jeroenh I did the best I could for testing my only computer right now is not strictly a development box so any tests I write end up giving very different results depending on what else happens to be sucking up system resources. I suppose I could take some averages but if the speed gain is a micro-optimization as every says then an average really isn't going to tell me anything.  Admittedly I am not the most knowledgeable in advanced testing like this.

Comment: @JeffWatkins it returns the same instance.

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks for that, it's an interesting result (the one I'd hoped for!). I'd try it myself but I'm not on a Windows box (or one with Mono) at the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just Replace it will perform slightly slower when there's *No Match* because of the additional checks that Replace does (e.g.)

```
if (replacement == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("replacement");
}
```

Regex.Replace does return the input if no matches are found so there's no memory issue here.

```
Match match = regex.Match(input, startat);
if (!match.Success)
{
    return input;
}
```

When there *is a match* the regex.Match fires twice once when you do it and again when replace does it. Which means Check and Replace will perform slower then.

So your results will be based on

- Do you expect a lot of matches or a lot of misses?
- When there are matches how does the fact that the `Regex.Match` will run twice overwelm the extra parameter checks? My guess is it probably will.

Comment: That's the problem especially with a VCARD there could be encoding like =0D in ANY value of a key:value pair.

So there could be a collection of Key:Value pairs that have the encoding in every line

and there is just as likely a chance that only one or two key:value pairs will have the encoding.

Comment: After working out some tests (See the edit for my question) I was able to determine that in pretty much all cases letting the regex do the straight replace is at minimum 25% faster than doing a string replace

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along the lines of a very specialized lexer with look-forward checking, *e.g.*,

```
outputBuffer := new StringBuilder
index := 0
max := input.Length
while index < max
    if input[ index ] == '%'
    && IsHexDigit( input[ index + 1 ] )
    && IsHexDigit( input[ index + 2 ] )
        outputBuffer.Append( ( char )int.Parse( input.Substring( index + 1, 2 )
        index += 3
        continue
    else
        outputBuffer.Append( input[ index ] )
        index ++;
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go with string replacement, it may be better to use [StringBuilder.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w.aspx) than string.Replace. (Will not create many temporary strings while replacing....)

Comment: I've found several articles that show that String.Replace is the fastest over StringBuilder.Replace and Regex.Replace

[String.Replace vs. StringBuilder.Replace vs. Regex.Replace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx)

[StringBuilder vs String Operations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14936/StringBuilder-vs-String-Fast-String-Operations-wit)

Comment: Besides at the point I need to do the replacement I'm already dealing with an enumeration of strings, shoving each existing string into a stringbuilder seems a bit excessive and unnecessary in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Taking some inspiration from some of the fine folks who chimed in, I managed to isolate and test the code in question.

In both cases I have a Parser Regex that handles breaking up each "line" of the vcard and a Decode Regex that handles capturing any encoded Hex numbers.

It occurred to me that regardless of my use of string.Replace or not I still had to depend on the Decode Regex to pick up the potential replacement hex codes.

I ran through several different scenarios to see if the numbers would change; including: Casting the Regex MatchCollection to a Dictionary to remove the complexity of the Match object and projecting the Decoding regex into a collection of distinct simple anonymous object with an Old and New string value for simple string.Replace calls

In the end no matter how I massaged the test using the String.Replace it came close but was always slower that letting the Decoded Regex do it's Replace thing.

The closest was about a 12% difference in speed.

In the end for those curious this is what ended up as the winning block of code

```
    var ParsedCollection = Parser.Matches(UnfoldedEncodeString).Cast<Match>().Select(m => new
    {
      Field = m.Groups["FIELD"].Value,
      Params = m.Groups["PARAM"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value),
      Encoding = m.Groups["ENCODING"].Value,
      Content = m.Groups["ENCODING"].Value.FirstOrDefault == 'Q' ? QuotePrintableDecodingParser.Replace(m.Groups["CONTENT"].Value, me => Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(me.Groups["HEX"].Value, 16)).ToString()) : m.Groups["CONTENT"].Value,
      Base64Content = ((m.Groups["ENCODING"].Value.FirstOrDefault() == 'B') ? Convert.FromBase64String(m.Groups["CONTENT"].Value.Trim()) : null)
    });
```

Gives me everything I need in one shot. All the Fields, their values, any parameters and the two most common encodings decoded all projected into a nicely packaged anonymous object.

and on the plus side only a little over 1000 nano seconds from string to parsed and decoded Anonymous Object (thank goodness for LINQ and extension methods) (based on 100,000 tests with around 4,000 length VCARD).